# Dataframe column sorting based on most common string

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have  pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name    Hobby
Andrew  Football
Kevin   Photo
Andrew  Football
Kevin   Games
Andrew  Travel
Kevin   Games
```

The desired result would be Andrew: Football; Kevin: Games. This could be either a dictionary or a db. I can not just sort for one name and afterwards do the idxmax of Hobbies, because my Name column can be updated with more or less names. I tried:

```
sorted = sorted.drop_duplicates()
sorted1 =  {k: g["Hobby"].tolist() for k,g in sorted.groupby("Names")}
```

but this would bring in all of the Hobbies and not only the most recurrent one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that will return a Series indexed by Name and the most common Hobby associated with:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Hobby'].agg(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).index[0])

Name
Andrew    Football
Kevin        Games
Name: Hobby, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the faster solution with double [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) and [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df3 = df.groupby(['Names', 'Hobby'])
        .size()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .nlargest(1)
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='Count')
```

Another solution is use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

df1 = df.groupby('Names')['Hobby'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

**Timings**:

```
In [52]: %timeit df.groupby(['Names', 'Hobby']).size().groupby(level=0).nlargest(1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name='Count')
1 loop, best of 3: 191 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit df.groupby('Names')['Hobby'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0])
1 loop, best of 3: 242 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit df.groupby('Names')['Hobby'].agg(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).index[0])
1 loop, best of 3: 345 ms per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
#[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L1 = ['Andrew', 'Kevin','Joe','John', 'Bob', 'Peter']
L2 = ['Football','Photo','Games','Travel']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':np.random.choice(L1, N), 
                   'Hobby': np.random.choice(L1, N)})

print (df)
```