# Pandas Multi-index: sort second column by frequency of values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame which consists of a series of SVO triples extracted from thousands of texts. For the particular dimension I am seeking to explore, I have reduced the SVO triples strictly to those using the pronouns he, she, and I. So, the data frame looks something like this:

| subject | verb | object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| he | contacted | parks |
| i | mentioned | dog |
| i | said | that |
| i | said | ruby |
| she | worked | office |
| she | had | dog |
| he | contact | company |

While I can use `df_.groupby(["subject"]).count()` to give me totals for each of the pronouns, what I would like to do is to group by the first column, the subject, and then sort the second column, the verb, by the most frequently occurring verbs, such that I had a result that looked something like:

| subject | verb | count [of verb] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| i | said | 2 |
| i | mentioned | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is it possible to do this within the pandas dataframe or do I need to use the dictionary of lists output by `df_.groupby("subject").groups`?

I'm getting stuck on how to `value_count` the second column, I think.

Comment: See if this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40799223/16836078

Comment: The output isn't t so explicit, doesn't look sorted. You should provide a meaningful minimal reproducible example and the matching expected output

Comment: Thanks, @KevinChoonLiangYew, that begins to give me a way forward. And, my apologies, mozway, the original had swapped the example two data tables.